# Building page with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been building my pages by including a `pageStart.html` and `pageEnd.html` files and then going about my business in between the two includes.

**pageStart.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
        <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

**pageEnd.html**

```
    </body>
</html>
```

This means I don't have to remember the entire contents, just to include them.

My problem now is that I want certain pages to load certain JS scripts but I have already closed the `head` and so can't (properly) declare new scripts. What would be a better way to go about doing this? Is this even a good idea? Should I just manually put the contents of the files in my PHP files and then add any extra needed scripts?

Comment: css belongs in the `head` (officially...), but scripts can be placed almost anywhere. Any specific reasons you need them in the `head`?

Comment: You can include JS scripts after the head tag as well.

Comment: @jeroen I thought it was good practice to have them included in the head.

Comment: "Some/Certain" JS scripts can be included outside `<head>` not all. @Dutchie432 --- Least, from my past experiences.

Comment: It's actually good practice to include them right before the `</body>` to avoid loading delays caused by (traditional / synchronous...) scripts. But there is no golden rule, it also depends on what you need the script for.

Comment: Contrary, it is considered better performance to place scripts a the end of the page, http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Google search Model View Controller

Comment: As jeroen said, there's nothing wrong with loading scripts in the body tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not really true. I've found this to be consistent as long as the JS file is included before it is being used and there are no conflicts with existing scripts.

Comment: Then there must have been something I was doing wrong or a conflict somewhere (in the past) as I stated from my own (past) experience. @Dutchie432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, a good web standard is to include the `js` files in your footer. This is because the page's `html/css` will finish and display a page quicker so the user gets some feedback about the page rendering.

I don't see anything wrong with placing a new `<script>` tag at the end of your page if you know that the `js` is ONLY going to be used on that page. Including it on 2 or more pages probably warrants the script to be included in the footer.

You can also lazy-load the `js`: [RequireJS lazyloading](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as, although the other answers answer my exact question, this answer corrects my ignorance and thus solves my problem in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

in your html header, add a placeholder where you want your scripts to appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
        <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {zScriptPlaceHolder}
    </head>
    <body>
```

then, echo the content (if that's the way you work) or add them to the general variable your storing your page into while replacing your placeholder with your chossen scripts:

```
echo str_replace('{zScriptPlaceHolder}',$scripts,file_get_contents("pageStart.html"));
$html.= str_replace('{zScriptPlaceHolder}',$scripts,file_get_contents("pageStart.html"));
```

that way your scripts will be in your header

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I have used a structure like this:

```
class Layout
{   
    public function Header($js = "")
    {
    ?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
        <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        if (strlen($js) > 0)
        {
        ?>
        <script><?php echo $js; ?></script>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        ?>
        </body>
</html><?php
    }
}

$layout = new Layout();
```

Then you simply use like this:

```
include "classes/layout.php";

$js = "alert('My inline JavaScript code');";

$layout->Header($js);
```

Them the closing tags `</body></html>` will be added at automatically at the end of the script. But you can do something similar to the `Header()` to it, like `Footer()`. You all can create a method like `addScript("js/some-jquery-plugin.js")` that will add that value to an array and will be printed in the `Header()` method.

This structure opens so many possibilities.

Comment: I like this solution, I tried to implement something like this but it got far to obfuscated quickly.

Comment: @Lerp sorry but don't got your point. What you mean with *obfuscated* ?

Comment: Obscure and unreadable. My attempt at something like the above, not your solution :)

Comment: @Lerp I got it. Well, when I was working on a project of mine, I used that for first time, and I like. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep scripts in the `pageStart.html` then change it to `pageStart.php` and do this:

**pageStart.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
        <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php
        if(isset($add_js) && is_array($add_js) && count($add_js) > 0){
            foreach($add_js as $k=>$v){
                echo '<script src="'.$v.'"></script>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
```

**someOtherPage.php**

```
$add_js = array();
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript1.js';
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript2.js';
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript3.js';
include('pageStart.php');

// go about your body business here
```

### And the same idea can be applied if you want to put it just before your `</body>`

**pageEnd.php**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($add_js) && is_array($add_js) && count($add_js) > 0){
        foreach($add_js as $k=>$v){
           echo '<script src="'.$v.'"></script>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**someOtherPage.php**

```
include('pageStart.php');

// go about your body business here

$add_js = array();
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript1.js';
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript2.js';
$add_js = 'pathTocustomscript3.js';
include('pageEnd.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use one html file to include, so, based on your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
            <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>(%otherscripts%)
        </head>
        <body>(%documentbody%)
        </body>
    </html>
```

I actually do not include the file, but read it with file_get_contents() in PHP, then use a simple str_replace to put my content in it. After that, i only have to echo it out. This ways you can add new scripts too, e.g:

```
$page = file_get_contents('page.html);
$page = str_replace('(%documentbody%)', $mycontent, $page);
$page = str_replace('(%otherscripts%)', $myscripts, $page);
```

Anyone has a better idea to replace content quickly?

Best, 
zimpee

Answer (score 0):

Delete the closing head tag from the pagestart and add it in the page you are working on. When you need a script include it in before the closing head tag. It is better to include the script between the head tags.